# Converting an int in a struct to a string in C

Tags: c

I am trying to convert int values from within a struct to a string so that I can write them to the header of a ppm file.

Struct is defined as such:

```
typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    int maxColourVal;
    FILE *ppmFilePointer;
} PpmStruct;
```

Function to create a new ppm file:

```
PpmStruct *newWritePpm(const char *filename, PpmStruct *parentPpm){
    FILE *outfile = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!outfile){
        printf("Unable to open '%s'\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    PpmStruct *newPpm;
    newPpm = (PpmStruct *)malloc(sizeof(PpmStruct));

    /* Populating ppm struct*/
    (*newPpm).width = (*parentPpm).width;
    (*newPpm).height = (*parentPpm).height;
    (*newPpm).maxColourVal = (*parentPpm).maxColourVal;
    (*newPpm).ppmFilePointer = outfile;

    /* writing outfile ppm header to file*/
    fputs("P6\n", outfile);
    fputs((*parentPpm).width, outfile);
    fputs(" ", outfile);
    fputs((*newPpm).height, outfile);
    fputs("\n", outfile);
    fputs((*newPpm).maxColourVal, outfile);
    fputs("\n", outfile);
    /* leaves pointer at start of binary pixel data section */

    return(newPpm);
}
```

On compile I get several similar warnings from the compiler:

```
ppmCommon.h: In function ‘newWritePpm’:
ppmCommon.h:75:8: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fputs’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  fputs((*parentPpm).width, outfile);
```

Comment: `(*newPpm).width` -> `newPpm->width` and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fputs` is for writing strings. `parentPpm->width` *is an integer*. For [Netppm formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) you need to output ASCII decimal integers. It is easiest to just use a single `fprintf` call for the whole header:

```
fprintf(outfile, "P6\n%d %d\n%d\n", 
        parentPpm->width, newPpm->height, newPpm->maxColourVal);
```

Comment: As a sidenote, `%d` is *only* appropriate for `int` values; for `long int` you'd want to use `%ld` and for `long long int` you'd want to use `%lld`...